# Is it possible to compile pre-ANSI (K&R-style) C code with Visual C++?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

We have some old C code with pre-ANSI (K&R-style) function declarations.  For example:

```
int foo(x, y)
double x, y;
{
    /* do some stuff */
}
```

Is there a compiler switch to enable support for this in Visual C++ 2008?

Comment: That code is still valid C (though old-style function definitions are "obsolescent").  You just need to tell VC to compile the code as C rather than C++.  (I don't know off the top of my head how to do that,  which is why this is a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: What is stoppoing you from downloading MS Visual Studio Express and trying? Just use a single file with such a declaration and you have your answer

Comment: @KeithThompson: Ah, so is it just a matter of using the [`/Tc` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx)?  I'll check to confirm that we have that turned on.

Comment: @Mawk: What's stopping me is that it's going to be easier for someone who already knows how to post an answer than for me to walk into the next room and try it out on my laptop that already has VC2008 installed on it.

Comment: @keith if the file has .c extension then msvc treats it as C. But since msvc isn't a real C compiler, it might gag on this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: My understanding is that MSVC has quite good C89/C90 compliance (but very poor C99 compliance).  In what sense is not not a real C compiler?

Comment: @keith I heard that it's the c++ compiler with some special rules to make it behave like a c compiler

Comment: @Mawg and KeithThompson: Yeah, that's why I posted this question.  I was talking with a coworker and I couldn't remember if MSVC supported this syntax, and my Google-fu was failing me, so I thought I'd try SO.  Turns out StackOverflow is faster than Google after all!  :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It doesn't matter how it implements C, as long as it does so correctly. Do you know of any failures to conform to the C89/C90 standard?

Comment: @Keith I wasn't aware that C89 adherence was good for msvc. I thought the efforts to conform were driven by herb sutter and were focused on c++. Anyway, I see no reason to doubt to what you say, so thanks for putting me right. It's a shame they only support a 25 year old standard for C but there are plenty of other good C compilers around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get this to compile put the code in a .c file vs. a .cpp.  This instructs Visual Studio to compile the code as C instead of C++