# Why K&R style code is not getting compiled with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to compile pre-ANSI (K&R-style) C code with Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949382/is-it-possible-to-compile-pre-ansi-kr-style-c-code-with-visual-c)

We are working on legacy code and it has function defined in K&R style,

```
void fun(a,b,c)
int a; int b; int c;    
{
 // ...
}
```

I know this is not ANSI standard, but valid C code, is there any way to make this code compile with Visual Studio (VS 2010 we are using).

Comment: i guess (don't know): missed `extern C`?

Comment: It [compiles](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ilm6w%246) on GCC 4.7.2. Just thought it might help narrow down the problem to VS.

Comment: It compiles on VS2010 too. What is the error?

Comment: This has been asked and answered at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949382/is-it-possible-to-compile-pre-ansi-kr-style-c-code-with-visual-c

Comment: Yes, I just now see suggested question also, but I didn't got proper answer. Answer doesn't solve problem.

Comment: These are errors I got, Error 1 error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier c:\documents and settings\lgi5-2\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ccc\ccc\f.cpp 6
Error 2 error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier c:\documents and settings\lgi5-2\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ccc\ccc\f.cpp 6
Error 3 error C2065: 'c' : undeclared identifier c:\documents and settings\lgi5-2\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ccc\ccc\f.cpp ...

Comment: @Pranit - The answer is that it is valid C code, but should not compile as C++. So name the file with `.c` and not `.cpp`.